# OnPropertyChanged() not working in MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, mahapps.metro

I searched through all other question with the same problem. But I can't find any solution from them.

**OnPropertyChanged** is firing but the Control is not updating. I'm using the **Mahapps.Metro ProgressRing Control**.

**View Code**

```
<controls:MetroWindow.Resources>
        <userObj:LoginViewLogic x:Key="UserData"/>
        <userObj:LoginViewLogic x:Key="LoginViewLogic"/>
    </controls:MetroWindow.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <Canvas>
            <controls:ProgressRing Name="ProgressRing"  Canvas.Left="133" Canvas.Top="154" Height="50" Width="35" IsActive="{Binding Source={StaticResource UserData},Path=UserData.IsProgressRingActive}"/>
        </Canvas>
    </Grid>
```

**ViewModel Code**

```
    public class LoginViewLogic {

    public LoginViewLogic() {

       _userData = new User(AppSettings.ReadCredentials(),(bool)loadedSettings); 
    }

    private User _userData;
    public User UserData
    {
        get { return _userData; }
        set { _userData = value; }
    }

    public async void Login() {

        _userData.IsProgressRingActive = true;
        var loginResult = await Stuff.Login(_userData);

        if (!loginResult) {
            MessageBox.Show("You have entered an invalid username or password",
                "Information", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
            _userData.IsProgressRingActive = false;
        }
    }
```

**Model Code**

```
 public class User : INotifyPropertyChanged {

        private bool _isProgressRingActive;
        public bool IsProgressRingActive {

            get { return _isProgressRingActive; }
            set {
                _isProgressRingActive = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("IsProgressRingActive");
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName) {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
```

Comment: Does your output window display any binding error?

Comment: Are you sure that you call the `Login` method on the correct `LoginViewLogic` instance? You have two of them, maybe while you bind to the `UserData` resource, you call the method on the `LoginViewLogic` resource? At least, a missing `INotifyPropertyChanged` implementation in the view model is not your problem (although it won't hurt to implement it).

Comment: There is no binding error everything else is binded the same way and working.I implemented NotChanged in the view  model.

Comment: `await Stuff.Login` Yeah, you're blocking the UI thread.

Comment: no im not blocking the ui, i found the problem the was at xaml binding code

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this:

```
<controls:MetroWindow.Resources>
        <userObj:LoginViewLogic x:Key="LoginViewLogic"/>
    </controls:MetroWindow.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <Canvas>
            <controls:ProgressRing Name="ProgressRing"  Canvas.Left="133" Canvas.Top="154" Height="50" Width="35" IsActive="{Binding Source={StaticResource LoginViewLogic},Path=UserData.IsProgressRingActive}"/>
        </Canvas>
    </Grid>
```

So you are only creating and binding to one instance of LoginViewLogic class?

Answer (score -1):

Your viewmodel should also raise a **PropertyChanged** event.
Try with below code.

```
public class LoginViewLogic : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public LoginViewLogic() 
    {
       _userData = new User(AppSettings.ReadCredentials(),(bool)loadedSettings); 
    }

    private User _userData;
    public User UserData
    {
        get { return _userData; }
        set { _userData = value; }
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName) {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));

}
```

Comment: Still the same problem.